# Read SMS for opt programically in Maui android

Tags: c#, android, maui

I am trying to read sms for otp in my maui appliaction(balzor).i tryied with BroadcastReceiver which was not working fine .now trying with LifecycleEvents i want to fire LogEvent whenever new message arrives to my phone.

```
                       public static class MauiProgram{
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        }).ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events => {


        events.AddAndroid(android => android
            .OnActivityResult((activity, requestCode, resultCode, data) => LogEvent("OnActivityResult", requestCode.ToString()))
            .OnStart((activity) => LogEvent("OnStart"))
            .OnCreate((activity, bundle) => LogEvent("OnCreate"))
            
            .OnStop((activity) => LogEvent("OnStop")));

        static void LogEvent(string eventName, string type = null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Lifecycle event: {eventName}{(type == null ? string.Empty : $" ({type})")}");
        }

    });




    builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: If you need to read OTP you should have a look here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview. You should be able to implement it with platform specific code (I did it with Xamarin Forms). That's the Google suggested way if your specific requirements is reading OTP, rather than implementing a broadcast receiver to read every message.